# FFMPEG - Windows Batch - Loudnorm Print to File

Tags: batch-file, ffmpeg

I would like to have the first three minutes of some M3u8 urls from a text file checked for loudness and have the results written to a file.

The following Windows batch code works in the Windows terminal. But the log.txt remains empty.

`for /F "tokens=*" %%A in (input.txt) do ffmpeg -i %%A -ss 0 -t 180 -af loudnorm=I=-16:TP=-1.5:LRA=15:print_format=summary -f null - >> log.txt`

Expect Output appended to file.

Answer (score 0):

My efforts to pipe loudnorm output to a file fails too. There is one thing that might help. FFMPEG console output directs to stderr so you could redirect the console output that way which will include the loudnorm summary. This might not be exactly what you want but with a little parsing should give you what you need. It might be worth setting -hide_banner while you are at it.

```
for /F "tokens=*" %%A in (input.txt) do ffmpeg -hide_banner -i %%A -ss 0 -t 180 -af loudnorm=I=-16:TP=-1.5:LRA=15:print_format=summary -f null - 2>> log.txt
```